# How to align text center and image right in one div using bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
                                        Text                            Image
```

I want to align the text in the center and image on the right in bootstrap but i am unable to do so

this is my html code

```
<div class="english-Box">
        <h1 class="text-center color-English">English</h1>
    <img class="eng-Img" src="images/abc.png"></img>
        </div>
```

this is the css code

```
.eng-Img{
   float:left;
  }
.color-English{
    padding-top: 14px;
    color: #7952b3;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }

  .english-Box{
    border-radius: 5px;
    Border:1px solid #7952b3;
    height: 60px;
    width:20%;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto 80px auto !important;
    float: none;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your image the `pull-right` class like :

```
<img class="eng-Img pull-right" src="images/abc.png"/>
```

Note that the `img` tag is a self-closing tag that should end with `>` no need for `</img>`.

You could use the bootstrap **[Grid-System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)** to arrange you div's like :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="english-Box row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <h1 class="color-English text-center">English</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img class="eng-Img pull-right" src="images/abc.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its putting the image down but on the right bottom not with text.

Comment: no in html the closing tag is not needed :) it's only necessary on XHTML

Comment: same as before as it was

Comment: Only XML or XHTML require self closing for non container tags, just like @TemaniAfif said. It is not required, and isn't valid, in HTML, though rendered by most browsers.

Comment: Thanks guys for your interventions, I meant there's no need for `</img>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap just use bootstrap float classes. Something like this will do the trick. Add 'float-left' class to 'h1' and 'float-right' to 'img'.

```
<div class="english-Box">
    <h1 class="text-center color-English float-left">English</h1>
    <img class="eng-Img float right" src="images/abc.png"></img>
</div>
```

And in css, give 'h1' a width. This will help h1's text to be center within that width.

```
.color-English {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with below html :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="english-Box">
    <h1 class="text-center color-English">English</h1>    
</div>
    <img class="eng-Img" src="images/abc.png" />
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
.container{
  position : relative;
  width : 100%;
}
.eng-Img{

   float:right;
  }
.color-English{
    padding-top: 14px;
    color: #7952b3;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
  }

  .english-Box{
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    Border:1px solid #7952b3;
    height: 60px;
    width:20%;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto 80px auto !important;
    left:50%;

  }
```

Wrap the whole content in a container class, and then use `positioning` as the content wrapper to be `relative` and its content to be `absolute`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give your image class `float-right` for bootstrap 4. `pull-right` is for bootstrap 3.

```
<img class="float-right eng-Img" src="images/abc.png"/>
```